# CSS <ul> <li> gap in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a CSS `<ul>`  `<li>` nested menu that works perfectly in IE 8 and firefox but in IE7 it produces a small gap between the elements.
this is my CSS:

```
#nav, #nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    position:static;/*the key for ie7*/
    line-height: 1.5em;

}

#nav li
{
    float: inherit;
    position: relative;
    width: 12em;
}
#nav ul
{

    position: absolute;
    width: 12em;
    top: 1.5em;
    display: none;
    left: auto;

}
#nav a:link, #nav a:active, #nav a:visited
{

    display: block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #258be8; /*#333;*/
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #258be8; /*#333;*/
}

#nav a:hover
{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;

}
#nav ul li a
{
    display: block;
    top: -1.5em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto; /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
    right: 12em;
    padding:0.5em; 
}

#nav ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
}

#nav ul li ul
{
    right: 13em;
    margin: 0px 0 0 10px; 
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul
{
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
}

#nav li
{
background: url(~/Scripts/ourDDL/ddlArrow.gif) no-repeat center left;
}

#divHead, #featuresDivHead
{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 12em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #99ccFF;
    margin: 1px;
}
/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html #nav li { float: left; height: 1%; }
* html #nav li a { height: 1%; }
/* End */
```

and here is an example for a menu:

```
<ul id='nav'><li><a href="#">Bookstore Online</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Study Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TV Broadcast</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Donations</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're displaying the `<li>` elements inline (to create a horizontal menu) the line-breaks between the sibling `<li>`s are being converted into a single white-space. You can either comment-out the spaces, or put all the siblings on the same line:

commenting-out:

```
...<li>element One</li><!--
--><li>element Two</li><!--
--><li>element Three</li>...
```

or:

```
...<li>element One</li
   ><li>element Two</li
   ><li>element Three</li>...
```

(in the latter example note the closing `>` of the `<li>` tags on the next line immediately preceding the next sibling)

or you can use same-line siblings:

```
...<li>element One</li><li>element Two</li><li>element Three</li>...
```

You could also just use `float: left` on the `li` elements, which takes them out of the inline document flow. Possibly a negative left-margin to move the `li` left to 'cover' the preceding whitespace, though it would likely take trial and error to find a suitable measurement to cover the space without covering the preceding `li` element.

Comment: Don't want to advertise my solution, but the above looks like a clutch to me :)

Comment: It is. I wasn't aware of the `vertical-align` solution. Nice find, and plus-one for that.

Answer (score 28):

I actually fixed it by setting `vertical-align: bottom` to LI elements (and yes, I didn't remove spaces and line breaks :)

Comment: Great solution! Christ I hate IE.

Comment: @DavidMasters every developer (especially web developers) hates IE. 
With M$'s "wanna be THE leader" policy I always expect 1+1 to equal 30tish... :D

Comment: Definitely appears to be the best solution. Should be marked as the correct answer in my opinion.

Comment: Unfortunately whatever answer is checked after 3 or 4 hours can no longer be unchecked. I found that out the hardway myself a couple times, either by prematurely accepting an answer to realize later it didn't work. Or someone coming along and providing a much better answer, and wanting to check that instead. Only to get an error via stack saying I couldnt change it cause I already accepted the other one more then x time ago. I think its a means of forcing users to carefully select there answers, as well as to prevent people from climbing ranks on stack in a way not so legit.

Comment: Works in IE7, not IE 8, 9 and 10 though.

Comment: for IE8+ I got it working using Sean Don's answer and also setting the width of the li to 100%. display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;

Answer (score 3):

It may be because of the spaces between the list items. You can either fix the problem by removing the spaces between the list items like this:

```
<ul id='nav'><li><a href="#">Bookstore Online</a></li><li><a href="#">Study Resources</a></li><li><a href="#">Service Information</a></li><li><a href="#">TV Broadcast</a></li><li><a href="#">Donations</a></li></ul>
```

Or this:

```
<ul id='nav'><li><a href="#">Bookstore Online</a></li><li
    ><a href="#">Study Resources</a></li><li
    ><a href="#">Service Information</a></li><li
    ><a href="#">TV Broadcast</a></li><li
    ><a href="#">Donations</a></li></ul>
```

Or if you want nicer-looking HTML, you can put comments between the list items:

```
<ul id='nav'><li><a href="#">Bookstore Online</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Study Resources</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Service Information</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">TV Broadcast</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Donations</a></li></ul>
```

There are also tricks to remove the spaces using CSS, as described [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/closing_the_gap_between_list_items_in_ie/).

Answer (score 3):

**Fix**:  Add zoom:1 and *display: inline to the element in CSS

**Original CSS**:

```
.blueberry .pager li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

**Fixed CSS**:

```
.blueberry .pager li {
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}
```

The asterisk (*) in front of display: inline allows for other browsers to ignore that line.

from: http://uncorkedstudios.com/2011/12/12/how-to-fix-the-ie7-and-inline-block-css-bug/

Comment: Adding only `display: inline` for `li` worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to make a horizontal nav? Try adding display:inline to your container.
EDIT:

NM. In ie6, they show up as a horizontal bar.
+1 for mikez's answer. that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your current model its the extra space between li tags. Really dumb IE thing. The following css however works to fix it and keep your li tags from being all on 1 line. (tested in IE7, Opera, Chrome)

```
<style type="text/css">
    #nav { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type: none; width:12em; }
    #nav li { position:relative; background:url(~/Scripts/ourDDL/ddlArrow.gif) no-repeat center left; display:inline; }
    #nav a, 
    #nav a:active, 
    #nav a:visited { display:block; padding:5px; border:1px solid #258be8; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; background-color:#258be8; width:100%; }
    #nav a:hover { background-color: #fff; color: #333; }
</style>
```

You had a lot of extra code for dropdowns maybe? anywho I didn't add that.

Answer (score -1):

you can add this styles to your styles.ie.css

```
/* for IE7 only */
*+html #nav { font-size: 0; line-height: 0;}
*+html #nav li {font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; }
```